# get specific projects that a user is a part of

Tags: c#, tfs

Here I am using IIdentityManagementService to retrieve a specified user by name. Now I want to retrieve only those team projects which they are a member of and can create tasks/workitems for in TFS. My program allows a user to create a task in TFS and I only want them to be able to see a list of the projects which they have access to for creating tasks/work items.

```
var tfsTpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://dotnettfs:8080/tfs/"));
identityService = tfsTpc.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
userId = identityService.ReadIdentity(
  IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName,
  strOutlookUser,
  MembershipQuery.Direct,
  ReadIdentityOptions.None
);

userTpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsTpc.Uri, userId.Descriptor);
cssService = (ICommonStructureService4)userTpc.GetService(typeof(ICommonStructureService4));

 wis = userTpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
 lstAllProjects.AddRange(cssService.ListAllProjects().ToList());
 List<string> lstViewProjectNames = lstAllProjects.Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
```

Right now, the list shows all projects within that software collection when I want it to show only those projects which the retrieved user has access to.

then they are able to create a task and specify the iteration and area for one of those projects.

```
var store = wis.Projects[0]; //should be a specified project, not the first element.
WorkItem pbi = new WorkItem(store.WorkItemTypes["Product Backlog Item"]);

pbi.IterationPath = lstIterations.Where(a => a.Name == selectedIteration.ToString())
                      .Select(a => a.Path).First().ToString();


pbi.AreaPath = lstAreas.Where(a => a.Name == selectedArea.ToString())
                      .Select(a => a.Path).First().ToString();
```

Comment: Have you looked at GetEffectivePermissions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.geteffectivepermissions.aspx Typically the source control root is $/TeamProjectName. You can probably just check the permissions on THAT. I haven't tried it though but it is what I would try if I did.

Comment: I cannot find the reference to VersionControl.

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client does not exist according to visual studio 2013.

nevermind, i found it.

Comment: Sounds like youa re missing a reference?

Comment: You might also have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262673/TFS-SDK-Get-Groups-Users-Permissions-using-TFS-API

Comment: it wasn't returning for any search results in my add reference search for some reason. I found it manually.

Comment: i tried what is being done here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262673/TFS-SDK-Get-Groups-Users-Permissions-using-TFS-API

it doesnt work for what I am trying to do. it also uses IGroupSecurityService which is depreciated and intellisense suggests using IIdentityManagementService which I am using.

Comment: What about getting the effective permissions?

Comment: @MikeCheel
for get effective permissions, what would I put for the 'server item'?
     
    var permissions = vcs.GetEffectivePermissions("username",     "serveritem");

Comment: The docs say server path and it is a string so I am guessing it would something like "$/MyTeamProject". I am going to try and do some actual code if I have time and see what I can turn up. I'm kinda busy at work atm but I will see what I can come up with. Also, I only have access currently to the 2010 api but I can't imagine it has changed too much along these lines.

Comment: Define the criteria for "they are a part of or are authorized to have access". A user can have access to version control but not to work items or vice versa.

Comment: @GuilioVian I have made an edit to further clarify what I mean by that. Basically I just want to get a list of Projects which they are actually members of. For example a team leader may have access to multiple projects or software collections and can create tasks for those. I want to retrieve those based on the retrieved user name.

Comment: Work Item permissions are based on areas and they can be applied to any subset. It seems to me it would be easier to have the user attempt to create the work item and then report failure than to (recursively) check all of their permissions. This is what you are after though right? Or just a list of team projects the user has access to?

Comment: @MikeCheel My thought was to first retrieve a list of Areas of projects which that user is a member of. Then once they select an area from a dropdown list, it will detect which project that area is for. Then the iterations will be generated from that project which they can then select. So I want to query all software collections and all team project collections for all projects for all areas which a user is a part of (for that project). Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what software collections means.

Comment: dotnettfs:8080/tfs/SoftwareCollection/   <- this is the softwarecollection

dotnettfs:8080/tfs/SoftwareCollection/TeamProjectCollection <- this is the team project collection

Comment: What does softwarecollection do? What exactly is it?

Comment: @MikeCheel software collection is a collection of team project collections and as far as I know does not have an actual object reference as far as visual studio IDE is concerned. It is basically where all the team project collections live (TfsTeamProjectCollection object).

Comment: It isn't standard TFS that's for sure. Why do you have so many team project collections? In most cases one will suffice (and often times even one team project is recommended).I'm still looking at this btw as I have time.

Comment: That is just the way it is set up where I work. It is being changed soon. I think the route I am taking will work. I am able to query all software collections which are of type CatalogNode I found out. From there I will iterate through all Project Collections and through all Projects for the team(s) that the user is a member of and thus the projects they are a part of. Then I will get all the AreaRootNodes for those projects and then get the iterations based off that.

Comment: Hey look what I found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.project.hasworkitemwriterights(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> I only want them to be able to see a list of the projects which they
>   have access to for creating tasks/work items.

Work items are tied to areas and areas are tied to team projects.

The basic steps are:

1) Connect to TFS as the user in question

2) Retrieve the team project in question

3) Get the areas for the team project in question

4) Check each one for the ability to create work items (you can probably get away with doing the recursive check on just the root area node)

The usings you will need (might not need all):

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

IIdentityManagementService identityManagementService = tpc.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = GetTfsCollection();
TeamFoundationIdentity identity = identityManagementService.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, @"Domain\username", MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
TfsTeamProjectCollection impersonatedTPC = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(this._tfsUri, this._tfsCollectionName), identity.Descriptor);
WorkItemStore impersonatedWIS = impersonatedTPC.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
ProjectCollection impersonatedProjects = impersonatedWIS.Projects;
foreach (Project p in impersonatedProjects)
{
    if (p.Name == "My Team Project")
    {
        NodeCollection areas = p.AreaRootNodes;
        foreach (Node area in areas)
        {
            if (area.HasWorkItemWriteRightsRecursive)
            {
                //They do have rights
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I call GetTfsCollection() which my own user defined function (this is just the class that I constructed with, passing in the root tfs uri and the collection name as string). I also didn't put in any exception handling, just showing the basics:

```
private TfsTeamProjectCollection GetTfsCollection()
{
    return TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(this._tfsUri, this._tfsCollectionName));            
}
```